# Bit coin core Settings/Receiving addresses

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, address, public-key, wallet-import-format

Under these settings in bitcoin core. does imported addresses (watch-only) appear under the settings as an official receiving address or it appears there because imported a wallet to watch.

Answer (score 1):

> <strike>**Settings/Receiving addresses**</strike> *[**Window/Receiving Addresses**]*

In Bitcoin core, under the menu *"Window"*, *"Receiving Addresses"* ...

[image]

... you'll normally see a list of addresses created using the *"Receive"* button. For example:

[image: list of receiving addresses]

---

> **does imported addresses (watch-only) appear under the <strike>settings</strike> *[Window/Receiving Addresses]* as an official receiving address**

If you import an address, it will be non-spendable, that is watch-only. I used the console window to run `importaddress  "1FeexV6bAHb8ybZjqQMjJrcCrHGW9sb6uF" "watchonly"` where "watchonly" was just my choice of label for this - you could put anything there.

Then that non-spendable address will appear in the list of receiving addresses

[image: list of addresses with a watch-only address at bottom]

This is potentially misleading. The tile says *"these are your Bitcoin addresses for receiving payments"* but you will **not** be able to spend any money sent to that last address. Even if you gave it some other label like "spendable" or "rainyday".

Comment: thanks! really helps